# How to dismiss a subView generated by code?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

In my project I want to show a first run view when starting the app for te first time. To do this I added a UIView to my mainViewCntroller.m. To dismiss this (overlayed) view I put a button on the view called acceptButton. What code do I have to add to the Button to remove this view from the stack?

What do I do wrong?

Here's my code:

```
- (void) firstRun {
if (((AppDelegate*)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).firstRun)
{
    CGFloat height = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height;
    CGFloat width = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width;

    NSLog(@"%f", height);

    CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);
    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
    myView.tag = 12345;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    // Create a ScrollView and a label
     UIScrollView *discScroll = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width - 20, self.view.frame.size.height -70)];
     discScroll.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

     UILabel *discLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,0,0)];
     discLabel.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;

     NSString *labelText = NSLocalizedString (@"InfoText",@"");
     [discLabel setText:labelText];

     // Tell the label to use an unlimited number of lines
     [discLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
     [discLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
     [discLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
     [discLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17]];
     discLabel.textColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:255 green:255 blue:255 alpha:1.0];
     //[infoLabel sizeToFit];

     CGSize infoLabelSize = [discLabel.text sizeWithFont:discLabel.font
     constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(discScroll.frame.size.width, 5000)
     lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

     discLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, infoLabelSize.width, infoLabelSize.height);
     discScroll.contentSize = infoLabelSize;

     [discScroll addSubview:discLabel];

     [self.view addSubview:discScroll];

    UIButton *acceptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake(110, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 74, 100, 44);
    // position in the parent view and set the size of the button
    [acceptButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    // add targets and actions
    [acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    // add to a view
    [self.view addSubview:acceptButton];


}
}

-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
{

[[self.myView viewWithTag:12345] removeFromSuperview];

}
```

In my mainViewController.h is the following property:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;
```

**EDIT** I've post the complete code. Maybe something else is in the way.

Comment: You are not clear at all about what the problem is. You simply state a goal and post some code. What is the actual problem with the code?

Comment: My guess is that your `buttonClicked` method should be: `[[self.view viewWithTag:12345] removeFromSuperview];`.

Comment: @Maddy.... you are great! Thanks a lot. I see I have to do the same thing far a scrollView I added and for the Button as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ive written it in Xcode, following Code works for me.

Ive opened a new XCode Project (Single View based), and just added following Code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
    myView.tag = 12345;
    [self.view addSubview:myView];

    UIButton *acceptButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    acceptButton.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
    [acceptButton setTitle:@"Click Me!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myView addSubview:acceptButton];

    [myView release];


}

- (void)buttonClicked{
    [[self.view viewWithTag:12345] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

This worked for me in iPhone Simulator.... Just this code in the MainViewController.m nothing else... Just give it a try, hope it works for you too :-)

Comment: Yes, it works but not in my own code. I've updated my question with the more complete code of the method.Maybe somthing else is in the way. (NSUserDefaults or so?) I'm puzzled. Thanks for helping me out.

Comment: Maddy has given it the last push. Had a mistake in the buttonClicked method. Must be "view" instead of myView. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

```
 [acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

when your method is called acceptButton, change to

```
 [acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(acceptButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Huh? The method is called `buttonClicked:`. I think the code in the question was updated since your post.

Answer (score 1):

your target is set to `buttonClicked` but you are using `acceptButton`

```
[acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];


-(IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender
 {
  [self.myView removeFromSuperview];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies with the `[acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:)` line. Change `buttonClicked` to your method `acceptButton:` in that call.

Answer (score 0):

```
[acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

The exception is clear, there is no function named "buttonClicked"

Just change the part of your code with below code;

```
[acceptButton addTarget:self action:@selector(acceptButton:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: Arrrggghh, stupid me. Silly enough I overlooked it completely. The error is gone but the view will not dissapear. Please advice?

Comment: Sorry i am a bit late, you've got the answer. You should also use [sender removeFromSuperview];

Answer (score 0):

just give it a tag...

```
UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
myView.backgroundColor = [UIColor scrollViewTexturedBackgroundColor];
myView.tag = 12345;
[self.view addSubview:myView];
[myView release];

-(IBAction)acceptButton:(id)sender{
[[self.view viewWithTag:12345] removeFromSuperview];
}
```

Also change

```
action:@selector(buttonClicked:)
```

to

```
action:@selector(acceptButton:)
```

Comment: Sorry, adding a tag didn't help. The view still persist.

Comment: Realy? Try to delete the @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *myView;... If you are working with tags you could release your subview right after adding it as subview... maybe the property lets it persist... Im doing it this way every time...

Comment: Silly enough Xcode reports an error after removing the property. "Property myView not found on object of type MainViewController *". I'm confused...

Comment: Give me a second, I will code it in quickly in Xcode to get it working... I will post it here as a new answer, if this is possible